# How to transform parameters to obtain an "unbounded" Johnson distribution?

Tags: distributions, identifiability

When applying the `R` fucntion [`SuppDists::FitJohnson()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SuppDists/versions/1.1-9.7/topics/Johnson) to data,  the Johnson distribution parameters are automatically calculated, as in the example below. Although I don't fully understand how the estimation is carried out, I assume the parameters are optimized based on the data input.

```
set.seed(123)
x = runif(1e4)
SuppDists::JohnsonFit(x)
#> $gamma
#> [1] 0.01280358
#> 
#> $delta
#> [1] 0.6780857
#> 
#> $xi
#> [1] -0.03668926
#> 
#> $lambda
#> [1] 1.073769
#> 
#> $type
#> [1] "SB"
```

The Johnson distribution CDF is described as

$$F_X(x) = \Phi \Big[\gamma + \delta f\Big(\dfrac{x - \epsilon}{\lambda}\Big)\Big]$$

where $\gamma, \delta, \epsilon, \lambda$ are the parameters and $f(\cdot)$ is the family. The are 4 possibility for Johnson Distribution families as explained in the [Biller and Nelson, 2002](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1172893), and each family defines the range of the data $X$ in $F_X(x)$.

**Once the parameters are estimated, is there a way to transform the parameters that were adjusted to a "normal" or "bounded" Johnson distribution into an "unbounded" distribution?**

With this transformation, I'd hope to understand/control how the CDF tails behave. The Johnson distribution is a transformation on the Normal distribution and, unsurprisingly, its support is $[-\infty, \infty]$. However, as aforementioned, if the family changes, the support for data $X$ also changes.

I saw there is no way to specify the family to which the data will be fitted to using the `R` function.

Comment: Could you explain what such a transform is intended to accomplish?  It sounds like you are asking how to change the result of the fit, but how or why is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @whuber. I hope the question is clearer now that I've provided more context.